# How to move the "shop by" block

Tags: magento2.2, layered-navigation, mobile-device

i need to move the "shop by" button in mobile, inside the toolbar block, and i cant do it. Any help?

Comment: Can you add a screenshot or some template/code reference so we can get a better understanding of what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i already moved it with a css styles !